# What is wrong in my finding frequency of substring in a strng

Tags: python

I am trying to find the no. of occurrence of a substring in a string. I know that `count` function can be used but it is for non-overlapping occurrences.

Here is my code I found online

```py
string = input("Enter the string: ");
sub_string = input("Enter the substring: ")
count = 0

for i in range(0, len(string)):
    for j in range(0, len(sub_string)):
        if string[i] == sub_string[j]:
            j += 1
        else:
            j = 0
    if j == len(sub_string):
        count += 1

print(count)
```

In this, in the 2nd loop we compare each element of `sub_string[j]` to `string[i]` which is same in that loop, then how j will increase & increase the count after checking in next if condition.

[image: Output of code goes here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the code you have is wrong, since it would pass the if check as long as the last character matches the matches the string, e.g. string
`"sagar is sagar not sa saga sagar r"` and substring `"sagar"` would return 4 rather than 3.

Since you use `j` both to count the number of matches as well as the index for the substring, it gets overwritten in the inner loop each iteration. This means that it would only need to match the very last letter to pass the check below the loop.

You might want to change it to something that checks each character starting at some position and denies it if it doesn't match, e.g.

```
string = input("Enter the string: ");
sub_string = input("Enter the substring: ")
count = 0

for i in range(0, len(string) - len(sub_string)):
    found = True
    for j in range(len(sub_string)):
        if string[i + j] != sub_string[j]:
            found = False
            break
    if found:
        count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case only the last elements are equal then the count will increment by one.

for ex:
if string is `seg`, and sub string is `sag` the the count will be one.
this happens because in the second loop when `j = len(substring)-1`, `g` from `seg` and `sag` will be detected as equal. so then count get increment by one.

```
string = input("Enter the string: ");
sub_string = input("Enter the substring: ")
count = 0

for i in range(0, len(string)):
    j=0
    while i+j< len(string) and  j <len(sub_string):
        if string[i+j] == sub_string[j]:
            j += 1
        else:
            break
    else:
        count += 1

print(count)
```

try this code, in there if while loop didn't get break count increment by one.